# Declaring a class in a Lua module and then instantiating it

Tags: class, oop, lua

I have a module called "MyClass.lua"  It contains this:

```
local _S = {}

function _S:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

return _S
```

In my main script, I refer to the module like this:

```
local c = require "MyClass"
local t = c.new()
```

This results in an error.  It's complaining about `setmetatable`.

```
<snip>\MyClass.lua:6: bad argument #2 to 'setmetatable' (nil or table expected)
```

I think I'm confused about what `setmetatable` does, the scope of `self`, and the role of `__index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `self` parameter is only implicit when using the OOP style.. You need to call it like this as well:

```
local t = c:new()
--         ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by it being implicit when using the OOP style.